# decoding a [String: Int] dictionary from JSON

Tags: json, swift

Using the quicktype.io I reflected the following JSON...

```
{
"message": "The data were fetched successfully.",
"data": {
    "date": "2022-07-22",
    "day": 149,
    "resource": "https://www.someWebsite.com",
    "stats": {
        "personnel_units": 39000,
        "tanks": 1704,
        "armoured_fighting_vehicles": 3920,
        "artillery_systems": 863,
        "mlrs": 251,
        "aa_warfare_systems": 113,
        "planes": 221,
        "helicopters": 188,
        "vehicles_fuel_tanks": 2803,
        "warships_cutters": 15,
        "cruise_missiles": 167,
        "uav_systems": 713,
        "special_military_equip": 72,
        "atgm_srbm_systems": 4
    },
    "increase": {
        "personnel_units": 150,
        "tanks": 0,
        "armoured_fighting_vehicles": 8,
        "artillery_systems": 4,
        "mlrs": 0,
        "aa_warfare_systems": 0,
        "planes": 0,
        "helicopters": 0,
        "vehicles_fuel_tanks": 22,
        "warships_cutters": 0,
        "cruise_missiles": 0,
        "uav_systems": 3,
        "special_military_equip": 0,
        "atgm_srbm_systems": 0
    }
}
}
```

into the classic Swift struct ...

```
    struct DataModel: Codable {
    var message: String
    var data: ObjectsModel
}

struct ObjectsModel: Codable {
    var date: String
    var day: Int
    var resource: String
    var stats, increase: [String: Int]
}
```

My issue is about `stats` and `increase` properties.
I simply cannot find a way to either set the CodingKeys for the keys that come in those properties or set the decoding strategy to convert them to CamelCase.

Calling  `decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase` doesn't seem to work and the keys are still displayed in SnakeCase...

Comment: please share the entire JSON snippet

Comment: You are decoding into a dictionary but the keys in the dictionary are not json keys and has nothing to do with the decoding in that sense. Actually the whole dictionary is a single value in itself as far as the decoding goes so no CodingKey enum or key decoding strategy is relevant.

Comment: We don’t know much about your json but are the keys of the dictionary always the same or very similar, if so then you could replace it with your own custom type.

Comment: @JulianSilvestri 
Please, take a look at the updated post. I added the entire JSON response along with my DataModel.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Please, take a look at the updated post. I added the entire JSON response along with my DataModel.

Comment: To me it looks like they are exactly the same so you could create your own custom type and use for both values so that both `stats` and `increase` is declared to be of that type instead of a dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as I understand, you need a new struct for both stats and increase, or it would be a better approach.

```
          struct DictionaryItem: Codable {
             let personnelUnits: Int 
             let tanks: Int
             let armouredFightingVehicles: Int

             enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { 
                 case personnelUnits = "personnel_units"
                 case tanks
                 ...
           }
```

That way you can use it defining increases and stats as DictionaryItem